# How to switch to Jikan V4

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am starting my first Python project and want to create a database using pandas and getting the data from JikanAPI for an anime selector. When I run the code it doesn't work because I think I am using V3 instead of V4. When I go on JikanAPI website I do not understand what I am reading so I don't know what to change. I used chatgpt to help get some of the code.

I tried going online but V4 was only recently implemented about a year ago so there was not much information.

```
from jikanpy import Jikan
import pandas as pd
jikan = Jikan()
anime_data = jikan.top(type = "anime", page = 1)
#create list of names
anime_list=[]
for anime in anime_data['top']:
    anime_info = {
        'Title': anime['title'],
        'Score': anime['score'],
        'Rank': anime['rank']
    }
anime_list.append(anime_info)
df= pd.DataFrame(anime_list)
print(df)
```